How to pass optional type arguments while omitting some other optional type arguments?
Say I have a function declaration looking something like this
declare function foo<T = string, S = number>(): void;

When I call this function, how can I specify the type of S e.g. S = string without overriding the default type of T?
I realize I can just set T = string but I see two drawbacks with that

if the function declaration changes in the future, I'm left with the previous default
the default type for T might be a complex type that is cumbersome to recreate in my scope

Note: I do not need the T to be inferred, using the default type is sufficient.

This is not directly supported, no. See the linked q/a above. The workaround from there is hard to describe for foo where you're not actually using T and S in the example. Presumably your actual function would have T or S appear somewhere in the params or return type. If we can assume that it returns [T, S] instead of void, then the workaround looks like this playground link.
